# Install different versions of VM tools

Tags: vmware-workstation, vmware-tools

Can we install different version of "VM toos" in a same image?

"Different version" means linux version and windows version.

The context of this question is:

We need to create a new VM image on Windows platforms, during this procedure, we need to install the "VM tools";

After the image is created, we need to run some tests with this image on Linxu platforms, then, we need to install the "VM tools" on Linux platforms.

can these 2 different versions of "VM tools" be installed in the same image?

Comment: I guess this question should be at [SuperUser](http://superuser.com)

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove/uninstall  one version of vmware tools and then only you can do it for other platform.
Removing and adding/upgrading vmware tools is not tricky. You need to have corresponding iso in datastore and connect the virtual machine's first virtual CD-ROM drive to the ISO image file that contains the VMware Tools installer for your guest operating system.